# AppsFlyer/Adjust/AppMetrica doesn't work with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, analytics, appsflyer-android-sdk

I made my first app with Expo and now I'm trying to set analytics. I tried different services (AppsFlyer, Adjust, AppMetrica, Flurry) but it seems that it doesn't work. Is it true that Expo doesn't work with them or I have to try harder to get it set?